# I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I think my condition is right

Tags: c, do-while, logical-operators, logical-or, logical-and

```
char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Digite aqui um caractere: ");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
    } while ((ch < 'A' && ch > 'Z' ) || (ch < 'a' && ch > 'z') || ch != '.');
    return ch;
```

I tried all sort of things on this condition and I can't make it happen. I want to return the value of "ch" when the input is [A-Z] or [a-z] or '.'.

Comment: Please choose a title which actually describes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the condition of the loop

```
while ((ch < 'A' && ch > 'Z' ) || (ch < 'a' && ch > 'z') || ch != '.');
```

for example thus subexpression

```
(ch < 'A' && ch > 'Z' )
```

is always evaluates to logical false because a character can not be at the same time less than `'A'` and greater than `'Z'`.

To simplify the condition at first rewrite it for the case when the loop should be interrupted.

The loop is interrupted when

```
( ( 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ) || ( 'a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') || ( ch == '.' ));
```

Now write its negation

```
!( ( 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ) || ( 'a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') || ( ch == '.' ));
```

You will get

```
( !( 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ) && !( 'a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') && !( ch == '.' ));
```

It is the same as

```
( ( !('A' <= ch ) || !( ch <= 'Z' ) ) && ( !( 'a' <= ch ) || !(ch <= 'z' )) && ( ch != '.' ));
```

or

```
( ( ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z' ) && ( ch < 'a' || ch > 'z' ) && ( ch != '.' ));
```

So you will have

```
while ( ( ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z' ) && ( ch < 'a' || ch > 'z' ) && ( ch != '.' ));
```

Another approach is to use standard function `tolower` or `toupper` declared in the header `<ctype.h>` to simplify the condition as for example

```
while ( ( toupper( ( unsigned char )ch ) < 'A' || toupper( unsigned char )ch ) > 'Z' ) && ( ch != '.' ));
```

Or according to the remarkable idea of  **@Gerhardh** you can also write

```
while ( !isalpha( ( unsigned char )ch ) && ( ch != '.' ));
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D I gotta study my logic better!

Comment: How about `!isalpha(ch) && (ch != '.')`?

Comment: @Gerhardh It is a good idea. :)